# Export memo data from Data Architect to Excel

Tags: excel, export, advantage-database-server

I am using Data Architect and want to export data of a table with memo fields.

If I export to CSV, everything works fine.

When I export to Excel (2003), the memo content is truncated and formatted with funny squares which is typical of a unicode encoding/decoding problem.

Ex : original string : "ABCD"
When exported to Excel : "A_B_" where the underscore is a square

I have looked into the devzone newsgroup but have not found any reference to this issue.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this as an error to the Sybase support? I found the support to be quite helpful.

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your comment. 
This is from [link](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=7) :
"Advantage Technical Services provides these newsgroups as a user supported area to exchange information, tips and techniques on Advantage products.
[...]
**If you do not have nntp (newsgroup) access, or would prefer a web forum, you can post your questions on StackOverflow and use the tag advantage-database-server**"

Comment: kuzkot: I knew that, in fact I asked (and answered) some ADS questions here myself, but as this seems to be an error in the Data Architect you might be better of to contact their technical support via MySybase (http://www.sybase.com/mysybase). You could also leave feedback at http://feedback.advantagedatabase.com/forums/2671-general.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could try to use some ODBC to Excel converter tool.

Writing a small program that exports data using ADS and OLE should be rather easy, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Advantage support rep and we saw your message from the feedback.advantagedatabase.com site.

I confirmed the behavior you've seen and am reporting it as a possible bug. In the meantime we did add the ability to directly copy the table and paste it into excel (e.g. select all of the data and then right click > copy records - this method allowed me to paste into an excel table  without issue). This feature is in ARC version 10.x.

Also, as noted you can also access the data using ODBC or OLE DB. You can download these drivers from http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/ under the "Product Download" section.

If you'd like further help or more detailed tracking of this you can open up a support ticket by calling 1-800-SYBASE5 (792.2735)

Regards

Josh